# Method in Java program won't pick up the user input

Tags: java, string, input

So I have some code here:

```
import java.util.*;

public class tester 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        String b;
        System.out.println("Choose a number 1-10.");
        int a = kb.nextInt();
        a = a * 2;
        a = a + 5;
        a = a * 50;
        System.out.println("Enter the year you were born in.");
        int c = kb.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Did you already have your birthday this year?");
        b = kb.nextLine();
        if (b.equals("yes"))
        {
            a = a + 1764;
        }
        else
        {
            a = a + 1763;
        }
        a = a - c;
        System.out.println(a);
        kb.close();
    }
}
```

I get the output here:

```
Choose a number 1-10.
5
Enter the year you were born in.
2014
Did you already have your birthday this year?
499
```

It seems to me as if the (String) b is completely ignored. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the `scanner.nextInt()` does not consume the new line character of the input typed by the user. You should call `kb.nextLine()` after the `scanner.nextInt()` just to consume the new line character left behind.

```
int c = kb.nextInt();
System.out.println("Did you already have your birthday this year?");
kb.nextLine(); //consumes new line character left by the last scanner.nextInt() call
b = kb.nextLine();
```

Or replace all your `kb.nextInt();` for `Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine());`

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
String b;
System.out.println("Choose a number 1-10.");
int a = 0;
try {
    a = Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine());
} catch (NumberFormatException numberFormatException) {
    a=0;
}
a = a * 2;
a = a + 5;
a = a * 50;
System.out.println("Enter the year you were born in.");
int c = 0;
try {
    c = Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine()); //consumes the new line character
} catch (NumberFormatException numberFormatException) {
    c=0;
}
System.out.println("Did you already have your birthday this year?");
b = kb.nextLine();
if (b.equals("yes")) {
    a = a + 1764;
} else {
    a = a + 1763;
}
a = a - c;
System.out.println(a);
kb.close();
```